# Why does lava sometimes stay in the Abyss Treasure Room?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

In Realm of the Mad God in the [Abyss of Demons](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/abyss-of-demons) there is a treasure room. Normally you attack the Abyss Idol and the room and hallway gradually fill up with lava. After you kill the Abyss Idol the lava normally disappears and the hallway is solid again. However, sometimes the lava stays like in this picture:

[image]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no current reason for this to happen, but if it does, it is a good sign, because if the lava stays after killing the Golden Idol, it means that there IS a 100% chance of there being another treasure room. On the other hand, this lava will never dissipate and it is a necessity to either:
*Tank it* This will do approximately 350 damage to you, so every class can tank it, and you can safely move to Malphas and the second Treasure Room
*Nexus* This is a bad idea. Nexusing instead of tanking the lava takes away any chance of the other two bosses. Hope this helped.
~Mesum